# Set colorbar at a range in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am making a bunch of colour plot figures in matplotlib and I want them all to have the same colour bar scale.  At the moment it varies depending on the max/min value in my array and I can’t work out how to set a maximum and minimum value for the colourbar.  I want to set the bounds between maximum of 0.8 and a minimum of 0.08.  I want the format of 0.08 instead of 8e-02.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.title(title, fontsize=24)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
modelmap = flopy.plot.ModelMap(model=mf)
lev_exp = np.arange(np.floor(np.log10(array.min())-1), 
np.ceil(np.log10(array.max())+1))
quadmesh = modelmap.plot_array(array,lev_exp, norm=colors.LogNorm())
cb = plt.colorbar(quadmesh, shrink=0.6, format='%.0e')
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the limits with `vmin=.08` and `vmax=.8` inside your plotting function.